# gcloud docker images scan - could not detect operating system of image, scan aborted

Tags: docker, gcloud

```
gcloud artifacts docker images scan hello-world
```

is throwing following error.

(gcloud.artifacts.docker.images.scan) Extraction failed: could not detect operating system of image, scan aborted

Any feedback on how to resolve this error?

Comment: Include the Dockerfile in your question

Comment: Check this document for information about supported OS for image scan. https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/os-overview#linux-versions

Comment: @JohnHanley hello-world is the sample image from docker https://docs.docker.com/engine/scan/#how-to-scan-images

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar is there an option to bypass this?

Comment: I think `hello-world` [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/master/Dockerfile-linux.template) is `FROM scratch` so there is no operating system to detect.

Comment: As suggested , check your docker file details, and share the same here.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar

FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]

Answer (score 1):

As per the official [document](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/os-overview) it is mentioned that the OS scanning overview supports vulnerability scanning for the following OS versions:

- Debian GNU/Linux - Versions: 9, 10, 11
- Ubuntu - Versions: 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 14.04, 14.10, 15.04, 15.10,
  16.04, 16.10, 17.04, 17.10, 18.04, 18.10, 20.04, 20.10, 21.04, 21.10, 22.04
- Alpine Linux - Versions: 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10,
  3.11, 3.12, 3.13, 3.14, 3.15, 3.16
- CentOS - Versions: 6, 7, 8, 9 and minor versions
- Redhat - Versions: 6, 7, 8, 9 and minor versions

Please check if the docker image you are using has one the above supported OS , if not then it would result in the scan not detecting the  operating system of the image, and aborts the scan with extraction failed error.
I would recommend you to have a look at the [Artifact Registry scanning](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr) and [Vulnerabilities scan](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-building-containers#use-vulnerability-scanning) document for further detailed information.